# How can I take reference to an element inside ng-template?

Tags: angular

I am using viewChild to take reference of that element but it is throwing me error native Element of undefined. I tried set time out also but still getting same error.

```
    <ng-template #publishAnywherePDF let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
      <div class="modal-header" *ngIf="!publishError && publishAnywhereStep != 2">
        <h4 class="modal-title" [hidden]="publishAnywhereStep !== 1" tabindex="0" #title>Download Publish Anywhere PDF</h4>
        <h4 class="modal-title" *ngIf="publishAnywhereStep == 3" tabindex="0">Publish Anywhere PDF</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d()" role="button">
          <i class="il-clear"></i>
        </button>
 <button type="button" role="button" class="btn btn-small btn-tertiary pull-right" (focus)="focus()">Cancel</button>
    <ng-template>
```

I am trying to access #title in h4

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-publish-anywhere-pdf',
  templateUrl: './publish-anywhere-pdf.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./publish-anywhere-pdf.component.scss']
})
export class PublishAnywherePdfComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild('title') titleRef: ElementRef;
    focus() {
    console.log(this.titleRef.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: so what is ```elRef?``` maybe you mean ```this.titleRef.nativeElement```?

Comment: Yes correct I was testing something what you have written is correct

Comment: ```ViewChild``` doesn't work because all content of ng-template isn't in DOM. You can use component approach instead of template and get a reference to what you need. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t5dfp7?file=app/service-component.ts)

Comment: try pass to focus the input. <button ...(focus)="focus(title)">